# Truth Table in SQL WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In TSQL WHERE clause, does the Truth Table logic apply?

For instance I have the following code:

```
WHERE (@Flag = 0 AND Title LIKE '%...%') OR (@Flag = 1 AND Title = '...')
```

In case @Flag = 0, First () will be True and second () will be False. So True OR False would result in True, hence, the second () won't have an effect on the query result. Is that true?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is true, or not false, or not not true.  :) It is true, that is correct.

Comment: Always be wary of operator precedence though. Grouping the two in `()` is the right strategy. [`AND` binds more tightly than `OR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx), so the `()` aren't strictly needed here, but they sure add readability.

Comment: Excellent point on the precedence, @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: One other thing to consider with these types of queries is that typically produce very poorly performing query plans.  If you're using this pattern with a large number of conditional branches, performance will suffer greatly as the plan that gets generated must work for any combination of parameter values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the truth table applies logic.

```
p   q   p AND q   p OR q
T   T   T         T
T   F   F         T
F   T   F         T
F   F   F         F
```

So when `p` is true and `q` is false, `p OR q` will evaluate to true.

As suggested, also worth taking a look at [3 valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Comparisons_with_NULL_and_the_three-valued_logic_.283VL.29):

[image]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/2/2c/3VL_Truth_Table.png/800px-3VL_Truth_Table.png))</sub>

Comment: Perhaps you can expand the table for the 3-value logic of SQL.